# Include an subarray in array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am so sorry If my question is stupid, but I couldn't find a solution...

I want to know if its possible to create an array in python, pretty like a json:

```
car = [
    ["Brand", "Citroen"],
    ["Model", "C4"],
    ["Details", "Lounge"],
    ["shift",
        [
            ["manual","5", "shifts"],
            ["automatic","5", "sequential"]
            ["automatic","5", "paddleshift"]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean print the output formatted?

Comment: This declaration is invalid, I would like to know if is there a way to do this. Thanks Padraic.

Comment: Are you talking about multidimensional list ?

Comment: Well, I failed on my first stackoverflow question.
After Padraic question, I copied the code and pasted and it worked -.-

The point is, I am actually using golang for web development, and using python to generate all those boring forms, based on a database structure.

My original code didn't worked, this code worked (appart from the missing colon after ["automatic","5", "sequential"].

Worked like a charm. Thanks Padraid and Achayan to quest me, so you guys indirectly said me was possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just missed a comma.

```
car = [
    ["Brand", "Citroen"],
    ["Model", "C4"],
    ["Details", "Lounge"],
    ["shift",
        [
            ["manual","5", "shifts"],
            ["automatic","5", "sequential"],
            ["automatic","5", "paddleshift"]
        ]
    ]
]

print(car)
```

Comment: yeah Sait and andiwand, thank you. On my original code I was getting an weird error 

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

even with that comma, maybe a bad indent. This code worked fine when I put that comma. 

Sorry to bother u all. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma:

```
car = [
    ["Brand", "Citroen"],
    ["Model", "C4"],
    ["Details", "Lounge"],
    ["shift",
        [
            ["manual","5", "shifts"],
            ["automatic","5", "sequential"],
            ["automatic","5", "paddleshift"]
        ]
    ]
]
```